# can't access .bash_profile

Tags: bash

So I was adding a path to my bash profile, and I accidentally started it with 'myname 1' instead of 'myname1'.  I think the space has messed something up.

When I open my terminal now, I get:

```
-bash: export: `1/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/XXXX/Library/PreferencePanes/MMPane.prefPane/Contents/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin': not a valid identifier
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: /Users/bin/git-prompt.sh: No such file or directory
```

I know the '1/ is super messed up, but now when I try to edit the profile again nothing works. I can't access it with nano or anything. I don't even think it can find my profile anymore.

Does anyone know how I can access that old profile to fix the edit I made?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's likely that your PATH environment variable has now been set to `myname`, and so trying to run a command `foo` will now only work if an executable named `myname/foo` exists.  The way around this is to give the absolute path of any program you want to execute.  For example, `nano` most likely resides in your `/usr/bin` directory, and so you should be able to run it to edit your `.bash_profile` by typing:

```
/usr/bin/nano ~/.bash_profile
```

If that's not the correct path, other likely locations for `nano` include `/usr/local/bin/nano` and `/usr/pkg/bin/nano`; the correct answer depends on your operating system and distribution thereof.

Answer (score 1):

Type the full path to the editor.

I assume the following will work:

/bin/vi .bash_profile